# Intellij android project setup - run button is disabled

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an android project with dependencies on actionbar sherlock. It compiles without error but the run Button is disabled. I have another android project that works fine and runs on my device, but I cannot see the difference between those projects - except I am able to run the one project and I am not able to run the other.

I would provide screenshots, but actually I don't have any idea where this problem is located.

Any idea?

Comment: Sometimes it might help to restart the IDE, or hit the 'synchronize' button manually. Which version of IDEA are you using? I am aware of v12 having synchronization issues sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Button is Disabled in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385172/run-button-is-disabled-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Did you set up a Run/Debug Configuration?

You should see a drop down to the left of the Run button; click it and click "Edit Configurations". In the top-left, click the "+" to add a new configuration, and select "Android Application". Select the Module (usually it's just your main project) to launch, choose the Target Device (hardware or emulator), give it a name, and then click OK.

Now you should be able to run with that configuration.

Comment: <no module > is displays. How can I generate module >

Comment: A minor note: If the project still does not allow running, try building the project "Build -> Build project", then redoing the run configurations, solved for me.

Answer (score 5):

In 2017, IntelliJ idea wants to index stuff for several minutes before it  will enable the Run option.

This appears to be by design.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click the class file with the main method on the project view.
2. Select Run.

Run configuration is created automatically so that you don't have to set it.