# Run Button is Disabled in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't click the run button. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: Disabled Run Button]

Comment: Does the drop-down list to the left of the Run button respond? If yes, then you should see an "Edit Configurations" option there, where you can define a run configuration.

Comment: Solved! I removed all the projects and created it again. It seemed some problem with directory position.

Comment: I had to clone the project again from version control system to a new location to make it work.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Click Run on the menu and then Edit Configurations... then click on Android Application on the left and click the + button. Choose Android Application from the pop-up menu. Then pick the module (its normally app or something like that). Then click apply and ok.

If you have more errors after that, try to re-import the project in Android Studio.

Comment: >Then pick the module
I tried until here. I could choose Module between (1)<no module> (2)AndroidStudioProjects. And I chose (2). Now, the run button is clickable. Thanks!

But, now, we get another error after clicking the run button. "Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again? [Edit] [Continue Anyway]" and after continuing anyway, "Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module "AndroidStudioProjects". Specify the output path in Configure Project"

Comment: In the configuration, "Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"

Comment: Did you try to import the project again? It sounds to me that your gradle configuration is broken.

Comment: I deleted all the projects I had, and created a new one. And it solved :) thanks!

Comment: I have downloaded a project but it doesn't have gradle.While edit config <no module> displayed. How can I enable Run Button

Comment: Go to Run, then EDIT configurations....Where when you try to find menu in Android Studio 1.3.+ versions

Comment: there are no modules showing when i select the module option.

Answer (score 131):

When creating the `Run Configuration`, the dropdown for Module had only `<no module>` for me. Invoking menu `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` added `app` to the dropdown for Module. Then the Run button became enabled.

Comment: Seems like this is pretty common in Android Studio 3.4 and higher

Comment: this solution still work with the latest android studio at this moment: 3.4.1 in a react native project.

Comment: Also worked with 3.4.1, asked to update Android Gradle plugin, after that run icon was enabled

Comment: Just needed this solution in Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1. Clearly this bug will be around for a while yet.

Comment: that work for me at android studio Dolphin

Comment: I didn't have the <no module> problem, but the Run button was disabled until I invoked File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files, so thanks!

Answer (score 54):

The above answer didn't work for me, instead closing the project and restaring the AS IDE worked for me.

Comment: This happened with me as well today. None of the answer worked except this , thanks!

Comment: I was using this solution, but we need another solution so not close/open project every time, but is better than other solutions

Comment: The only thing that works for me is restarting the IDE. The problem is that it happens very often.

Answer (score 43):

just to go **File -> Sync Project with Gradle files** then it solves problem.

Comment: sync with gradle helped me realize that i need to update android studio to be able to run the project. Thx!!

Answer (score 31):

Just click the dropdown button on left side of RUN button (in your image the dropdown which is in red box) select 'app' option from that and RUN button will be enabled.

Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I already read your answer, but I couldn't understand. Then I Clicked the `Run` option and the `Green Button` which is actually the Run button is enabled, I clicked and select the `App` and it works. Later, I realized that this was what your talking about. You must add Screenshot. LOL

Answer (score 19):

for flutter project, if the run button is disabled then you have to

tools>> flutter>> flutter packages get >>enter your flutter sdk path >>finish

This should solve your problem...

Answer (score 8):

Run 'app' button disable issue coming sometimes in Android Studio Dolphin

[image]

Sync your project with gradle files

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a Mac, try clicking on File, then click on "Sync project with Gradle files" .... Run button should turn green again in a few seconds.

Answer (score 6):

open your existing application by selecting **build.gradle** file. it will automatically sync the project and run button will be clickable

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Above answer didn't work for me, just do click File -> Invalidate/cache -> Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 4):

It was quite silly for me, I just opened the *Run > Run Configurations* window
everything seemed to be fine there, I didn't change anything, when I closed the window the button was enabled.

Answer (score 3):

If you have changed jdk version then go to File->Project Structure->Select SDK Location from left bar->update JDK Location in editbar in right bar.

Answer (score 3):

If your IDE is in power save mode, then the run button etc. are also disabled.

You can verify this via the file -> power save mode, make sure it is disabled.

[image: Disable power save mode to enable the run button]

Answer (score 2):

if you're importing an eclipse project to android studio, you'll also encounter the same issue as above. Double Check if grade>app has 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' on the top as sometimes android studio imports it as a library.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reconfigure the FlutterSDK path in Android Studio: Go to Setting -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter and set the path to Flutter SDK

Comment: Thanks. This only solution worked for me. After flutter upgrade my Run button was disabled

Answer (score 2):

I just clicked on the debug icon and it started working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### `Build`->`Clean Project`

make the run button enable again in my case

Answer (score 2):

For me increasing the version of compile SDK to latest solved my issue, Go to

> build.gradle(app-level)

```
compileSdkVersion 30
```

Because My Emulator is Api-level 30

Answer (score 1):

- Select the **project view** in the android studio.
- Remove **all** **gradle folders**.
- Restart the android studio.

This will work.

The issue is happening since the gradle was configured for an android studio in another machine and the files pushed on the git and are using in your studio.

After removing these gradle files and restarting the studio, the studio will generate gradle files for your system. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the wrong folder.... Verify is your root folder in Android studio has the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run the **Flutter** Project in **Android Studio**, and the run button is disabled then here is the solution

[image]

Click on **add configuration**

[image]

and select **Flutter** and then select the main class in dataentrypoint

Answer (score 1):

1. goto android studio terminal and paste
   flutter packages get
2. goto Files->Repair IDE
   if your problem goes away then select the option 'Everything ok or works for me' like option otherwise select other option and the problem goes away
3. The IDE will restart in the step2 but still if it does not restart then manually restart IDE

Answer (score 1):

dart was not enabeld

1. goto setting search for enable dart or you will see dart option there
2. enable dart and give it will ask you for the dart SDK path give the path 'C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk' but check your path of the given example directory
3. choose the below box project file and then apply and ok to exit
   this will enable your RUN button

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me using Android studio on flutter project:

```
File > Repair IDE
```

After an alert "Repair IDE" appears asking if the IDE already works fine, press **Rescan Projects Indexes** untill the run button works fine

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to go to that multiselect button, then "Edit Configurations" -> Go to  "+" and select the module (in this case it would be an app if you do not have a multiproject -> then apply and OK

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Linux** where I had a **symlink** in my home folder pointing to a folder containing the Android Studio projects. Loading a project using the symlink failed, loading a project from the folder where the symlink is pointing to worked!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me twice, and then I figured out it happened after I upgraded my flutter version. When I opened (flutter SDK path) in (flutter) tab in (system preferences) I found it empty.

***Solution was*** to point out to flutter directory on my disk from (flutter SDK path) in (flutter) tab in (Android studio preferences).

Answer (score 0):

`Run` button is bounded with `Configuration` that is why you should check if your project is build, synced and indexed and after that you can select a Configuration

Answer (score 0):

For me, more than 1 instance of `adb` was initialized and due to this run button was disabled. I had to open `ActivityManager` (on mac) and kill all the initialized `adb` instances.

Answer (score 0):

go to Build-> Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a different build variant (in the Build Variants view), then reselecting the initial build variant, fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue with your Flutter config setup in android studio. Go to edit config and check if the flutter path is setup properly. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, in the gradle scripts my local.properties file didnt exist so ide wasnt able to find the location of project.and the reason was, i started the project with dragging file of project to android studio. AFter that i closed the ide and started the project from android studio -> projects side. it worked for me[image]