# Run button is disabled and not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

[image: Run/Debug Conifuration]

No errors in project and not even in Manifest.

I tried this solution [Run Button is Disabled in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385172/run-button-is-disabled-in-android-studio) but failed to resolve my problem.

Please help to enable Run button..!

Comment: to the left of the run button there is a selector, in your screenshot is empty, you should select the module you want to run (app module i guess)

Comment: Oh! Thanks lelloman.. it worked!

Comment: you're welcome, have fun :)

Comment: dang! just this?. wasted a couple of hour for this. thanks @lelloman you rock.