# Trying to run project successfully in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I opened this library in Android Studio: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn?autodive=0

However, I'm not able to run the app itself. I have tried multiple things (too many to list here) to get it to work but to no avail. For example, I've taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385172/run-button-is-disabled-in-android-studio) but it's not helpful for this specific project.

[see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDSlD.png)

Can someone tell me step by step what to do to run this
project's app successfully?

Comment: It could be because of many things, first please provide more information about warning or error you have got, then where did you get the project? from GitHub or you just copied and paste the codes from the provided link?

Comment: I downloaded it from the link. I don't get any errors. The run button is just greyed out. The simplest way is to try running the project yourself. To download it you just have to click `tgz` @FarshidABZ

Comment: Probably there is no any configuration to run this app. Make a new project and copy all files from that project.

Comment: @grabarz121 That didn't work out, please try it out yourself